# opening a file gives a sYSMALLOc assertion failure

Tags: c, file, pointers, malloc, valgrind

I've been struggling with this bug for a while and I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
//the code for the function that is being called
//charset is a const char[] consisting of 91 characters
//charset_size is 91
void set_sequence(char keyword[], int keyword_size){

    sequence = malloc(keyword_size);

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < keyword_size; i++){

        for(j = 0; j < charset_size; j++){

            if(keyword[i] == charset[j]){

                sequence[i] = j;

            }

        }

    }

    sequence_size = keyword_size;

}

//the function call in main
set_sequence("foo bar\n", 8);

//there's supposed to be stuff done here with sequence that I haven't implemented yet
free(sequence); //sequence is a global variable that I use the function to set

FILE* dest = fopen("cipher", "w");
```

The reason I included the file bit is because when it's there, I get the assertion failure, but when it's commented out the code runs absolutely fine (I have nothing after that line because I was trying to pinpoint the problem).

I ran the code through valgrind's memcheck `valgrind --tool=memcheck ../bin/cipher` to see what the issue is, but I can't make sense of it. Here's the output:

```
==10608== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10608== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10608== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10608== Command: ../bin/cipher -e testfile
Program running in encrypt mode
Open source file: success
Allocate memory for raw_input: success
Read source file: success
Allocate memory for input: success
input set-> freeing raw_input
==10608== Invalid write of size 4
==10608==    at 0x80486DC: set_sequence (in /home/hugo/Programming/C++/Cipher
==10608==    by 0x8048A86: main (in /home/hugo/Programming/C++/Cipher/bin/cipher)
==10608==  Address 0x41f6688 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10608==    at 0x402BB7A: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==10608==    by 0x804868C: set_sequence (in /home/hugo/Programming/C++/Cipher/bin/cipher
==10608==    by 0x8048A86: main (in /home/hugo/Programming/C++/Cipher/bin/cipher)
==10608== 
==10608== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10608==     in use at exit: 704 bytes in 2 blocks
==10608==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 4 frees, 1,793 bytes allocated
==10608== 
==10608== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10608==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10608==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10608==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10608==    still reachable: 704 bytes in 2 blocks
==10608==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10608== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10608== 
==10608== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10608== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not giving the declaration of sequence.  Is it a char array or an int array?  If it is an int array, your malloc is wrong, it would need to allocate `keyword_size * sizeof(int)` bytes

Comment: Sorry I took a while to get to your answer. I've been really busy. Your solution worked. I totally forgot that a `char` is 1 byte while an `int` is 4 bytes, so of course while it was bad practice it went unnoticed until I tried doing the same for an `int`.